# Is there a term for "genocide" of the elderly?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word *infanticide* means:

> killing of babies: the practice of killing newborn babies

Is there an equivalent term for killing the elderly?

Comment: I would like to formally note that this question has absolutely nothing to do with traditional holiday gatherings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The word you are looking for is one of either:

- ***senicide*** — as in *senior, senile, senectitude, senescence, senate, senator*
- ***geronticide*** — as in *gerontocracy, ˌgerontologist, gerontophilia, gerontophobe*

[Quoth Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senicide):

> **Senicide** or **geronticide** is the abandonment to death, suicide, or killing of the elderly.

Apparently *senicide* was preferred  until the middle part of the past century, but now *geronticide* has caught up and surpassed it, being now preferred by about 3 to 1.

See this [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=senicide%2Cgeronticide%2Cgeriatricide&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Csenicide%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsenicide%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSenicide%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cgeronticide%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgeronticide%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGeronticide%3B%2Cc0):

[image: Google n-gram of senicide, geronticide, and the so-called but non-existent geriatricide]

Answer (score 0):

Geriatricide

from geriatric meaning pertaining to the elderly.

Geronticide does not appear to be current, (I found it in several dictionaries, but not in any news) whereas *geriatricide* is hitting headlines left and right.

Searching my browser cache I find these instances (not complete):
http://politicalhat.com/2013/03/09/passive-geriatricide-comes-to-america/
http://www.sodahead.com/united-states/top-five-worst-obamacare-taxes-coming-in-2013/question-3208033/
http://goodsensepolitics.blogspot.com/2009/07/obamacare-solution-geriatricide.html
http://www.zerohedge.com/contributed/2012-12-13/going-geriatricidal
http://www.bmj.com/content/1/6065/903.5
http://stlouisteaparty.com/2009/07/obamacare-not-just-bad-policy-but-evil/

Comment: Geriater actually means "curer/doctor of old people", from *iatêr* "doctor", from *iaomai* "I cure". http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=lsj&lang=el&word=i%29ath%2fr&filter=CUTF8 — http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=lsj&lang=el&word=i%29a%2fomai&filter=CUTF8

Comment: @Cerberus Geriatricide comes from [geriatric](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/geriatric), "Of or relating to the aged or to characteristics of the aging process." - I've seen it pretty often as well

Comment: @Izkata: That definition is only correct in the context of medicine (where healing is included), or mockery, or perhaps colloquialism (so of a far lower register than *genocide*). Notice how the relevant definitions below have *(Medicine)*. Derived senses are possible, but not to the extent of using it to express the opposite of what medicine does. It comes from *old* + *cure*.

Comment: @Cerberus Only 1 of the 3 dictionaries listed use the "medicine" qualifier.  That word has already become more general than it originally was.

Comment: @Izkata: Definitely not as part of a compound meaning the opposite of its true meaning and in the higher registers.